# Glide Image showing Blur in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I use glide in fragment using recycler view but images are not showing properly.

please suggest me to slove this issue

```
 Glide.with(context)
     .load( image_url)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.pic)
     .error(R.drawable.pic)
     .fitCenter()
     .into(Viewholder.imageView);
```

Comment: Check This https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations

Answer (score 0):

By default Glide uses low resolution images to save data and improve performance.

```
boolean isHighResolution = true;

 BitmapRequestBuilder<String, Bitmap> builder = Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(url)
                .asBitmap()
                .format(isHighResolution
                        ? DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888
                        : DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)
builder.into(imageView);
```

You can try this code, and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The image to be loaded size should be greater and doesn't loaded properly and it is blurred.
use `Bitmap` and compress the image like below

```
Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(album.getBannerUrl())
        .asBitmap()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                // Do something with bitmap here.
                holder3.headerimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(album.getBannerUrl().get(0))
                        .asBitmap()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                                // Do something with bitmap here.
                                holder3.headerimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```